# Invoke Javascript function immediately on Server Side in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using the below code to call a JavaScript function on the server side, but the JavaScript function is not called immediately and is only executed only after all codes on the Server side is finished executing. Is there any way invoke the JavaScript function call immediately.

```
protected string Pass_value()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "answer",getanswer(), true);

    answer = hdnfldVariable.Value.ToString();
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: It's been about 6-7 years since I've last written websites, but as far as I remember, Javascript runs on the client side, not on the server side...

Comment: you can call the javascript function that is included in your HTML page

Comment: @ZoharPeled: there a multiple way's these days: some use the following stucture: 1) load page 2) open connection to the server 3) wait for the server to response (and reconnect at timeout) 4) "invoke" on server response... I must say, its a "hack" but in general, it is like invoking the script server side.

Comment: You could use something like SignalR to communicate between the server and the client, but it sounds like you have a design problem if you need to have a persistent connection between your server and your client.

Comment: @Stefan Even back in those days you could use different techniques to run client side scripts as a response to something that happened on the server side. If memory serves, SignalR was a shiny brand new product, for instance. and also, back then new developers got confused all the time with the server/client nature of asp3 and asp.net development.  Just thought it was something worth mentioning.

Comment: @ZoharPeled SignalR is a framework for websockets that falls back to longpull requests when websockets weren't supported. Also, it came after ASP.NET Ajax Extensions and partial page load behaviors.

Comment: Santosh, the document isn't even rendered to the client until all the webform server-side code is "finished executing".  please review [Page Lifecycles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) of webforms.  When the `OutputStream` in the `HttpContext.Response` `object` is written (or `WriteEnd` in control behavior), that is when the document markup is completed and the client gets the body content to their document type uri request.  It is just `IO` mechanism that results in markup.

Comment: @BrettCaswell I know what SignalR is, I only mentioned that as an example of a technology that was available even way back when I used to write websites...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling a javascript method in backend code, try to call your backend method with ajax and then use return value in javascript code.